# Best way to link a Double based on conditional Month and Year - JAVA

Tags: java, data-structures

Based on the given Year and Month, I need to return a specific Double value.

There are a bunch of values (+3 years worth).
What should I use for that? Nested dictionary? IF conditionals?

SOLUTION I did and find best:

Read Jon Skeet's comment

Comment: Are they densely populated, i.e. "One value for each month, for a set period of time?" If so, an array where the index is "Months since the start of the period" seems pretty simple.

Comment: My god, that is revolutionary thinking!!

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: The user, Basil Bourque, provided a better solution than the one I provided below by using Java's `YearMonth` class:

```
Map<YearMonth, Double> dates = new HashMap<>();

dates.put(YearMonth.of(2017, Month.APRIL), 55.0);
dates.put(YearMonth.of(2017, Month.MARCH), 50.0);
dates.put(YearMonth.of(2017, Month.FEBRUARY), 35.5);

System.out.println(dates.get(YearMonth.of(2017, Month.MARCH)));

>> 50.0
```

---

I recommend looking into [Guava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava)’s [`Table`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) data structure which allows you to map two keys of arbitrary types to a single value of an arbitrary type.  Using the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html):

```
Table<Integer, Month, Double> dates = HashBasedTable.create();

dates.put(2017, Month.APRIL, 55.0);
dates.put(2017, Month.MARCH, 50.0);
dates.put(2017, Month.FEBRUARY, 35.5);

System.out.println(dates.get(2017, Month.MARCH));

>> 50.0
```

---

If you'd rather not use an external library, you can emulate it with a nested [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

```
Map<Integer, Map<Month, Double>> dates = new HashMap<>();

Map<Month, Double> thisYear = new HashMap<>();

thisYear.put(Month.APRIL, 55.0);
thisYear.put(Month.MARCH, 50.0);
thisYear.put(Month.FEBRUARY, 35.5);

dates.put(2017, thisYear);

System.out.println(dates.get(2017).get(Month.MARCH));

>> 50.0
```

Comment: How do I use an external library? Never did it before... Would you recommend that?

Comment: Personally I love using external libraries.  Depending on your memory requirement for the program, an array might be a better choice as Jon said earlier, although it would require some helper methods to determine the correct index that a year and month correspond to.  The use of an external library depends on (or the lack of) the IDE that you develop with.  You'll have to add the library to your project's build path and import the correct classes.

Comment: Even simpler: Use [**`YearMonth`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) object as the key in a simple (un-nested) `Map`. Example:  `dates.put( YearMonth.of( 2017 , Month.APRIL ) , 55.0 )`

Comment: @BasilBourque I can't believe I never knew about that class!

Comment: @JacobG. I suggest you add a third section to your Answer showing a simple Map with YearMonth as key. Keep your other sections intact as it is all interesting.

Comment: @BasilBourque Will do!